# Flushing buffer with fgets

Tags: c

I used to use `fflush(stdin)`. I read that this is not a good way to get rid of the extra characters and that it is better to use fgets like this:

```
fgets(buffer,maxsize,stdin);
```

In cases that I want to dispose of those extra chars...what kind of buffer should I use? Could I redirect in some kind of "buffer of no return"? Or do I have to use a finite size array?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? Skipping to the end of a line?

Comment: I would like to read an integer and "throw away" all remaining line input.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using fflush(stdin)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2979209/using-fflushstdin)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://c-faq.com/stdio/stdinflush2.html

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: @NullUserException No, it would be preferable to close this post as the question has already been answered [multiple times](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=fflush+stdin+undefined+behavior).

Answer (score 2):

use `consumetoendofline(stdin)` instead :)

```
int consumetoendofline(FILE *where) {
    int ch;
    while (((ch = fgetc(where)) != '\n') && (ch != EOF)) /* void */;
    return ch;
}
```

You can (**and should**) even test the return value to see if the stream has reached its end, or if there is probably more data waiting ...